# Can wp_list_comments output into variable?

Tags: plugin-development, functions, variables, comments

Is there any way how to output `wp_list_comments()` into a variable?

Something like `$output = wp_list_comments(array('reverse_top_level' => false ), $comments);`

I am writing a plugin and it would be handy to use standard WordPress function instead of writing my own.

Comment: That's the kind of question one has to ask to the Manual: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments

Comment: What is it that your Plugin is actually trying to do with the comments? There might be a solution other than using `wp_list_comments()`.

Comment: The plugin displays a post with comments as a home page. This is done also via ajax. I want to do progressive loading of comments so it seems to me that I might need to write my own `wp_list_comments`. I thought I could avoid that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the default usage this is impossible due to the nature of the default comment walker which always directly outputs. But the function allows to provide a custom walker.

Further reading about custom walkers:
[Codex Class reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker)
[example custom walker class](http://shinraholdings.com/621/custom-walker-to-extend-the-walker_comment-class/)

You could also use output buffering to save it into a variable (this is considered to be dirty):

```
ob_start();
wp_list_comments(array('reverse_top_level' => false ), $comments);
$variable = ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: So `walker`, that's probably what @brasofilo meant in his comment. Well it is not explained in Codex for wp_list_comments. I'll try and comment here. Thank you especially for the second link :-)

Comment: @Radek If you want a quick solution maybe output buffering is the way to go. It will be hard to do with a custom walker as `wp_list_comments()` doesn't have a return value in the first place ...

Comment: I was just about to reactivate my answer and suggest output buffering, but you covered that now. +1

Answer (score 0):

According to Function Reference for [wp_list_comments](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments), you can set the arg Echo to false to return the list.

I imagine the default walker will not echo the code if this is set to false.

```
wp_list_comments(array('reverse_top_level' => false, 'echo' => false), $comments);
```